# Which version of Visual Studio covers ActiveX?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, activex

I would like to use an ActiveX control, more exactly "Microsoft Tabstrip control, version 5.0 (SP2)" but this is not possible due to license problems.

As mentioned in the answer on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479249/adding-a-tabpage-control-to-a-progress-4gl-windows-application-yields-a-license), this problem can be solved by installing an old version of Visual Studio (the installation of another environment, using that control, automatically handles the licensing issues of that control, also for other environments, at least that's how I understood it). I have installed the most recent version (2019, 16.8.3), which seems not to be a good idea.

So, there are three ways to proceed now:

- Either I uninstall my Visual Studio and replace it by an older version. In that case, which version do I need to use?
- Either I add the mentioned control (or ActiveX as a whole) to my list of "Workloads", "Individual Components" ("Tools" menu, "Get tools and features..." menu item).
- Either I use the extention handling feature to add (the mentioned) ActiveX control(s) ("Extensions" menu, "Manage extensions" menu item).

**Edit after more investigation**
In the meantime I've installed Visual Studio 2017, version 15.0, but this seems not to solve the issue. In top of that, I have no idea on how to include an ActiveX control to a basic Windows Form.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've managed getting the license to work, installing "Visual Basic 6 (VB6), Service Pack 6".